# How to display query in a TextView

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a method for displaying a query:

```
public Cursor getQuery() {

    String Fav="SELECT score, difficulty, date FROM score LIMIT 15'";
    Cursor c=db.rawQuery(Fav,null);
    return c;
    }
```

How will I use this in my OnCreate()'s textview?

Comment: what you want to use in your textview?

Comment: Iterate your cursor, get needed data from it and setText to your textview.

Comment: TextView is fine for getting going, but it looks like you want to use a ListView in the long run here to display the full hall-of-fame

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to display the resultant data that you got through the query.

Now, to display data into TextView, you have to write down a code to **iterate through the cursor**.

For example:

```
String strData = "";
if (c!= null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
         strData += cursor.getString(Fieldindex));            
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}

textview.setText(strData);
```